# How to compare SEM estimation methods in R?

Tags: r, monte-carlo, structural-equation-modeling, estimators

I would like to use several estimators in SEM (e.g. ML vs Yuan-Bentler vs DWLS) and then by using Monte-Carlo approach compare:

(a) average relative bias of the estimators,

(b) average relative bias of standard error estimates,

(c) relative bias of chi-square statistics, and

(d) the model rejection rate associated with the chi-square statistic at an 
alpha level of .05

What would be the best way to do this in R? Would appreciate provided example as well.

Comment: This is a very big question, and the answer depends on what you already know.  Look into the simsem package - but if you know how to do MC simulations, and you know how to do SEM (and know a little R), it's pretty straightforward, even without that. I don't know how to answer, because I don't know what you don't know. (Also, this isn't really on topic for CrossValidated.)

Comment: I know R and SEM but quite confused with simsem. I imagine that I would have to run SEM model with lavaan and get parameter estimate and st. error values using both estimators and then run simulations with both estimators as well, and substract the respective values for each and see which provides smallest difference from true value calculated with lavaan. I dont know how to run simulations in simsem to get the simulated values. Am I doing it right with: sim(1000, n=nrow(data), model = fit), fit being lavaan object created by sem() function. And do I later substract the values?

Comment: Also I am unsure where to look for model rejection rate value in simsem

Comment: You might want to ask on the lavaan google group. Specific questions about software are off topic on CrossValidated.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I did do that, hopefully it will become clearer, thank you!

Comment: :) I saw you did that.